Add default locale when I enter URL for the first time
Hello I want to add locale to my URL.
When I start the app my "default URL" is http://localhost:5173 and the page looks like this:

I get this error:

And I want to get this:

To get it I just have to click on any nav item or change locale, but I want for app to do it itself since I get no content on page without seleceted locale.
My main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import i18n from './i18n'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

const app = createApp(App)
// localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en')
// localStorage.setItem('user-locale', 'en')
app.use(createPinia())
app.use(i18n)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')

i18n.js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '@/i18n/locales/en.json'

export default createI18n({
    locale: localStorage.getItem('locale'),
    fallbackLocale: import.meta.env.VITE_FALLBACK_LOCALE,
    legacy: false,
    globalInjection: true,
    messages: { en }
})

translation.js
import i18n from "@/i18n"
import { nextTick } from "vue"
const Trans = {
    get supportedLocales(){
        return import.meta.env.VITE_SUPPORTED_LOCALES
    },
    get defaultLocale(){
        return import.meta.env.VITE_DEFAULT_LOCALE
    },
    set currentLocale(newLocale){
        i18n.global.locale.value = newLocale
    },
    get currentLocale(){
        return i18n.global.locale.value
    },
    isLocaleSupported(locale){
        return Trans.supportedLocales.includes(locale);
    },
    getUserLocale(){
        const locale = window.navigator.language ||
            window.navigator.userLanguage ||
            Trans.defaultLocale

        return {
            locale: locale,
            localeRegion: locale.split('-')[0]
        }
    },
    getPersistedLocale(){
        const persistedLocale = localStorage.getItem("user-locale")

        if(Trans.isLocaleSupported(persistedLocale)){
            return persistedLocale
        }else{
            return null
        }
    },
    guessDefaultLocale(){
        const userPersistedLocale = Trans.getPersistedLocale()
        if(userPersistedLocale){
            return userPersistedLocale
        }

        const userPreferredLocale = Trans.getUserLocale()

        if(Trans.isLocaleSupported(userPreferredLocale.locale)){
            return userPreferredLocale.locale
        }
        if(Trans.isLocaleSupported(userPreferredLocale.localeNoRegion)){
            return userPreferredLocale.localeNoRegion
        }
        return Trans.defaultLocale
    },
    async switchLanguage(newLocale){
        await Trans.loadLocaleMessages(newLocale)
        Trans.currentLocale = newLocale
        document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("lang", newLocale)
        localStorage.setItem("user-locale", newLocale)
    },
    async loadLocaleMessages(locale){
        if(!i18n.global.availableLocales.includes(locale)){
            const messages = await import(`@/i18n/locales/${locale}.json`)
            i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages.default)
        }
        return nextTick()
    },
    async routeMiddleware(to, from, next){
        const paramLocale = to.params.locale
        if(!Trans.isLocaleSupported(paramLocale)){
            return next(Trans.guessDefaultLocale())
        }

        await Trans.switchLanguage(paramLocale)

        return next()
    },
    i18nRoute(to){
        return {
            ...to,
            params:{
                locale: Trans.currentLocale,
                ...to.params
            }
        }
    }
}
export default Trans


Could use a middleware for that.

in translation.js is routeMiddlewre()

what does import.meta.env.VITE_FALLBACK_LOCALE return?

fallback locale from my .env file. If that is what you mean.
And in my routeMiddleware() to.params.locale is empty string

Can I something like this to my middleware?
if(to.params.locale == ''){             to.params.locale = 'en'         }

But what is the actual value of that variable in the .env file? is it 'en'?

Yes it is 'en'. When I do if statement from top, I get page content but url doesn't get language prefix.

Without knowing what library or how your translations are handled. Usually you can add a fallback language. For example with i18n you can do something similar to this.
i18n.init({
    "resStore": resources,
    "fallbackLng": 'en',
    "debug": true,
    "lng": document.getElementById('select_languages_dropdown').value
}, function (t) {
    $(document).i18n();     
});

But it all depends on your code and how you have implemented the translation functionality. Can you provide some more details or are small running example?

I just did. if something else is needed to show I will.
